# d3.selectAll.call a component factory function

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js, functional-programming

I would like a new `function` getting called on each element in the `selectAll` resultset.

If I do `d3.selectAll(...).call(factory(...))`, the same function is called on every element.
`factory(...)` returns a *component*, which might have state.

Is there something in the D3 API to do this? Or will I have to come up with something like `d3.selectAll(...).each(function() { d3.select(this).call(factory(...)) })`? Would that work?

Comment: Use `.each(function() { factory(d3.select(this), ...); })`.

Comment: `factory` returns a function that takes a selection. So `.each(function() { factory(...)(d3.select(this)) })`?

Comment: Oh right, yes. The `.call()` is equivalent, but I think it makes it less clear what's happening.

Comment: On a separate note, I would refactor the factory function to return a function that can operate on selections of more than one element.

Comment: Thank you! The *component* does accept a selection of more than one element but it keeps state (which it shouldn't), so essentially I get multiple instances of the same component

Comment: Can the _state_ be moved from the factory into the `data` you bind with the selection? If yes, then you can use the state from the `data` in the call to `.each`:  `.each(function (d, i) { ... })`.